# Find Span Within Span Using Python and Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to scrape the text ("9/10") in the span contained in `<span class"_1JRNOw">`. I had thought the code below would do it but I get a `Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//span[@class='_1JRNOw']"}` error.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@class='_1JRNOw']").text
```

Can anyone see what I've done wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one see if it works for you:

```
ele = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class='_1JRNOw']/span")
print("Text is: " + ele.text)
```

Comment: Thanks enthusiasticCoder. It gives the same error unfortunately.

Comment: would it be possible to share the URL of the page? I might be able to help you more.

Comment: Thanks guys. I've spent most of the weekend trying to figure out why these were not working. It turns out that after logging in through an iframe the content was contained in an ordinary frame so switching back before running the statements did the job. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

If **Glad text** is going to `remain same`, **not changing dynamically** (Assumption).

You could create an **xpath** based on **Glad** that could fetch you `9/10`.

xpath `//span[text()='Glad']//following-sibling::span/span`

and try it like this :

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[text()='Glad']//following-sibling::span/span").text
```

you could put some wait, or Explicit waits to have more stable automation script.

**Update  :**

Use this **xpath**

```
(//div[@data-kib-type='oauth']//descendant::span)[1]
```

But you'd have to change the [1] to something else, may be `[3]` or `[4]`. Please do that in chrome dev tools.

**PS :** Please check in the `dev tools` (Google chrome) if we have **unique** entry in `HTML DOM` or not.

**Steps to check:**

`Press F12 in Chrome` -> go to `element` section -> do a `CTRL  + F` -> then paste the `xpath` and see, if your desired `element` is getting **highlighted** with `1/1` matching node.

Comment: Thank you @cruisepandey. Glad is dynamic unfortunately but the @ will not change.

Comment: hmm.. `@` is actually of no use for us in xpath 1.0, I need to see more outer HTML to give you more reliable locator.

Comment: I've added more html. Thanks

Comment: Please see above.